# How are the values $3\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ determined?

Tags: geometry

Those values $\sqrt{2}$ and $3\sqrt{2}$

[image]

How do they suppose to match with $MB=BN=2$?

[image]

Comment: Is $S$ supposed to be $DB\cap MN$?

Answer (score 3):

The point $S$ should be the intersection point of $DB$ and $MN$.

Then, note that a triangle $SNB$ is an isosceles right triangle with its hypotenuse $NB=2.$

Comment: Why is SB not $sqrt(2^2+2^2)$?

Comment: Since $SB:NB=1:\sqrt 2$, $SB=2/\sqrt 2=\sqrt 2.$

Comment: @WardWalter: $\sqrt{2^2+2^2}=MN$, not $SB.$

Comment: How do you know SB:NB is 1 : sqrt(2)?

Comment: For any isosceles right triangle, (the length of its hypotenuse):(the lenght of another edge)$=\sqrt 2:1$.

Answer (score 3):

Draw the bottom square $ABCD$!

[image]

I've added the point $T$: the centre of the square $ABCD$.

The computation is essentially not different from the one given by mathlove in the earlier answer: the square $MBNT$ has sides of length $2$, its diagonal $TB$ has length $2 \sqrt{2}$, and $S$ is in the middle, so $SB = \sqrt{2}$.

And, of course, analoguously, $ABCD$ has sides of length $4$, its diagonal $DB$ has length $4 \sqrt{2}$, so $DS = 3\sqrt{2}$.